# Category of Frechet Spaces is Topological?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $sFre_{\mathbb{R}}$ *(resp. $Fre_{\mathbb{R}}$)* denote the category of *(resp. separable)* Fr\'{e}chet spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ as objects, and bounded linear operators as morphisms.

Is this a topological concrete category over $\mathbb{R}-Vect$; in the sense of [this post](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category).  In particular, is it [cototal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total%20category)?

Comment: Since I didn‘t manage to work through the definitions that you link to, this is just a tentative answer.  The category of Fréchet spaces has neither limits  of (non-countable) cospectra nor of (infinite) spectra in general (in particular, no uncountable products or infinite direct sums. Hence I suspect that this is a negative.

Comment: I did not know this.  If you like to post this as an answer I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posted as an answer at the OP‘s request: Since the category of Fréchet spaces doesn‘t admit products and sums in general, the answer would appear to be negative.  This is analogous to the fact that the category of metric spaces is apparently not topological whereas that of uniform spaces is (for similar reasons).

Comment: Thanks user131781 :)